# notify when a TCP port start listening

Tags: linux-networking, tcp

I need to be notified **exactly** when an application **start** `LISTENING` on any/specified TCP port.

is there anything like

1. configuring an application to log this event
2. using a library in any programming language(C/C++ is preferred), so that it provides ability to stands in the middle and log this event
3. or any other idea, **EXCEPT** watching `netstat` or watching SYN packet received in any way (`tcpdump`, `iptable`, ...)

Comment: Use the audit daemon for this. `man auditctl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using auditd; ask it to audit all calls to `bind`(2) and `listen`(2) -- the former so you can see what port is being bound to, and the latter to know when the listening starts.